# Sum frequencies and join labels in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
    Var1 Freq
1   6    1
2   7    4
3   8    1
4   10   2
5   11   6
6   12   1
7   13   2
8   15   1
```

What I'd like is to generate "bins", in other words, sum frequencies that have variables 5-9, 10-14, 15-19... and so on. This way getting:

```
    Var1    Freq
1   5-9     6
2   10-14   11
3   15-19   ...
```

No idea about doing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cut`

```
dat <- structure(list(Var1 = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L), 
Freq = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))


with(dat, aggregate(Freq, 
    list(Var1=cut(Var1, breaks=c(4,9,14,19),labels=c('5-9',  '10-14', '15-19'))),
       FUN=sum))
#   Var1  x
# 1   5-9  6
# 2 10-14 11
# 3 15-19  1
```

#### Update

If you have many breaks:

```
res1 <- with(dat, aggregate(Freq, list(Var1=cut(Var1, breaks=seq(4,19, by=5))),FUN=sum))
```

Creating labels:

```
library(stringr)
indx1 <- scan(text=str_trim(gsub("[[:punct:]]+"," ",res1$Var1)),sep="")

transform(res1,Var1=apply(rbind(indx1[c(T,F)]+1,indx1[c(F,T)]),2,paste,collapse="-"))
#   Var1  x
#1   5-9  6
#2 10-14 11
#3 15-19  1
```

Comment: I have to put a lot of breaks up to 2000, there's a way to do it automatically?

Comment: did you mean  seq(4,19, by=5)
#[1]  4  9 14 19